# display the output in the same page using php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

im new to php.i created a page in php containing chk boxes ,input fields and retrive the data from the database(mysql) and also use the javascript.
i h've a problem in this ,that is i want to display the output in the same page.

i created the code like this,i want the output in same page,but it shows error.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $con=mysql_connect("localhost","demosdef_review","review123");
if(!$con)
{
    die('could nt connect 2 the server');
}
mysql_select_db("demosdef_review", $con);
$state = $_POST["state"];
$country = $_POST['country'];

$contry = "USA";

if($country==1)
{
$result = mysql_query("SELECT address FROM storelocator WHERE countryid='1' AND id='$state'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  echo $row['address'];
}
else
{
$result = mysql_query("SELECT address FROM storelocator WHERE countryid='$country'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  echo $row['address'];
}

}
?>

    enter code here

        <div class=buy>
        <a href="dealer.php">Dealer Enquiry</a>
        </div><br/> 
        <div class=buyfont>Authorized Retailers</div>
        <div><a href="http://www.archiversonline.com/stores"><img src="images/archivers.png"><br/></a>
        <a href="http://www.archiversannex.com/Books-And-SoftwareSoftware-And-Accessoriesdefault.aspx?PageID=20&CategoryID=48"/>
        <img src="images/logo_archivers_annex.png" ></a><br/><br/>

    <a href="http://www.hobbylobby.com/storelocator"/><img src="images/logo_hobbylobby.png"></a><br/><br/>
    <a href="http://www.walgreens.com/storelocator/find.jsp"/><img src="images/logo_walgreens.png"></a></div><br/>
    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>
    <p>
                <label for="country" style="padding-right: 2px;">Country</label><select name="country" value="countryid"
                 id="countryid" 
                onchange="sub()" style="width:120px;">
                <option value="1">USA</option>
                <option value="2">CANADA</option>
                <option value="3">UK</option>
                <option value="4">AUSTRALIA</option>
                <option value="5">ITALY</option>
                 <option value="6">GUATEMALA</option>
                <option value="7">NEW ZEALAND</option></select></p>
                <p>
<label for="state" style="padding-right: 14px;">State</label>
<select id="state" name="state" value="state"  style="width:120px">
<option value="7">Alabama</option>
            <option value="8">Alaska</option>
            <option value="9">Arizona</option>
            <option value="10">Arkansas</option>
            <option value="11">California</option>
            <option value="12">Colorado</option>
            <option value="13">Connecticut</option>
            <option value="43">Florida</option>
            <option value="14">Georgia</option>
            <option value="15">Idaho</option>
            <option value="16">Illinois</option>
</select></p> <br/>
     <input class="dealer-submit" type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="buy_func()"/>
                  </form>  
     <script type="text/javascript">
        function sub()

        {
    var x=document.getElementById("countryid").selectedIndex;
    var y=document.getElementById("countryid").options;
    var z = document.forms[0].state;
    if(y[x].index==0){
    z.disabled = false;}
    else if(y[x].index>0) {
    z.disabled = true;}}
        </script>
```

Comment: Is this a correct copy? Because you missed a closing " in form's action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML markup has an error

```
<a href="http://www.hobbylobby.com/storelocator"/>
```

It should be

```
<a href="http://www.hobbylobby.com/storelocator">
```

Also try

```
<form method="POST" action="">
```

Keeping the action blank will post it to the same page itself

And replace your submit button with this

```
<input class="dealer-submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onClick="buy_func()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of the submit button, if its set `isset($_GET('submit'))` then display the results

does that solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

submit is the type of the element, 'Submit' is the value you are looking for:

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['Submit']){

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the backslash at the end of the line:

```
<a href="http://www.hobbylobby.com/storelocator"/>
                                                ^
```